# Cron job errors with "No such file or directory" even when the file DOES actually exist?

Tags: php, unix, cron

I am getting the following three lines in an error message in /var/mail/username after the following job runs in crontab...

```
15 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertPropertyRESI.php
```

Errors:

```
/applications/mamp/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertpropertyRESI.php: line 1: ?php: No such file or directory
/applications/mamp/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertpropertyRESI.php: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `'initialize.php''
/applications/mamp/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertpropertyRESI.php: line 3: `require_once('initialize.php');
```

The PHP script I am trying to execute DOES in fact exist, and I have made absolutely sure the spelling is correct several times. I ran a crontab on another script before and it worked just fine...any ideas??

The 2nd & 3rd Errors are from line 3 in the following script (the one I am trying to run with the crontab):

```
<?php
    require_once('initialize.php');
    require_once('insertPropertyTypes.php');

    $sDate;
    if(isset($_GET['startDate'])) {
        $sDate = $_GET['startDate'];
    } else {
        $sDate = '';
    }

    $insertResi = new InsertPropertyTypes('Listing', $sDate, 'RESI');
?>
```

When I run my script **insertPropertyRESI.php** in the browser, it runs just fine???? Also, initialize.php and insertPropertyTypes.php are in the same directory as insertPropertyRESI.php

I am using MAMP with PHP 5.3.5

thakns for the help :?

Comment: what does your cron entry look like? I have a feeling you're not prepending the `php` on your command...

Comment: What's the exact line for this task in your crontab file?

Comment: my bad, just edited the post `15 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertPropertyRESI.php`

Comment: Try running `php -f /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertPropertyRESI.php` on the commandline. If that works, then use that in the cron.

Comment: @qweet is there any way I can specify a different PHP installation, like `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are trying to execute a script which does not have a valid [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29).
Add the shebang as the first line of the script like this (adjust path of course):

```
#!/usr/bin/php
```

Or change the crontab entry to:

```
15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertPropertyRESI.php
```

Comment: I am having an issue with that installation of PHP (see my comment below). I tried using the path to MAMP's PHP installation at `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php` -- for both the shebang and as a prefix in the job entry itself...no luck...I will post the errors in a moment

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it runs in your browser is because your server is configured to automagically compile and serve PHP files.

Cron on the other hand, doesn't have that luxury; by default it will run anything that you put into it as a `bash` script.

From the looks of your Cronjob, you're running the PHP file without using the `php` parser, and as such Cron tries to run the script as a `bash` script.

If you put `php -f` in front of the location of the PHP script, you are telling Cron to run the command using the `php` parts, you should find that it will now run.

Alternatively, you could edit your code and prepend `#!/usr/bin/php` to the beginning of the script. When Cron runs this file, it will use `php` to run the command, instead of `bash`.

Comment: When I use php -f (loading from /usr/bin/php) I get some output that shows that the script begins running but hits a fatal error with the message: `file {$class_name} could not be found` . Since I am using mamp, I tried using the path to MAMP's installation of PHP: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php -f /path/to/script.php` and THIS method caused the script to execute...still no luck with the crontab though, will post errors in a minute. To make sure, I DO or DO NOT include the -f if I set the php path INLINE and not in a #! shebang?

Comment: this is ancient but it should read `#!/usr/bin/php`, not `!#/usr/bin/php`

Answer (score 2):

Running a php file on the command line is different than running it within web server like apache. To run a php script on the command line, you need to:

1. Install the package php-cli as this may not be installed by default.
2. Make sure you have the comment '!#/usr/bin/php' in the first line and make sure you set 'x' permission on your php script.
3. Alternatgively to 2, you just run the script by calling it using 'php your_script'

Comment: The php is installed, as it comes pre-installed with MAMP -- I am using a MAMP setup. It is installed in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php`. Is there any way I can use this installation in my crontab instead of the one in /usr/bin/php? The one in /usr is older, version 5.2, and is giving me an error that I am not getting with PHP 5.3. I did run the script with php -f /my/script and got the error I mentioned `file {$class_name} could not be found`; when I run the script using the MAMP php path, the error goes away and the script executes, but the crontab doesn't like it :? Please advise

Comment: Simply specify the full path when calling your script like `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php /path/to/your/script.php`.

Comment: I tried that, but it appears that it is not executing at all. Currently, my only method of checking for crontab executions is through the mail notifications; I don't get any mail when I use that method. Is there an alternate method that I can use to check for errors or for other information about my cron jobs?

Comment: Here is the exact line: `*/1 * * * * /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/bin/php /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/iconimageryidx/includes/insertPropertyRESI.php`

Comment: Can someone that can edit only a few characters fix the typo? "Alternatgively"

Comment: Shebang should be #! in answer, not !#: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29